# Console input with Qt Creator

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I'm developping a very simple app on my Mac using QtCreator.

It's a console application and I want the user to enter its name, and then I display his name. Here is the code :

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int ArgC, char* ArgV[])
{
    char Name[1000];

    std::cout << "Type your name : ";
    std::cin >> Name;

    std::cout << "Hello " << Name << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

When running this app with QtCreator, the string "Type your name :" is displayed in the 'Application Output' tab. But if I type some text and press the enter key, nothing is happening.

What's wrong ?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I found a solution. With Qt Creator 1.3.0 (on Mac OS X), here is what I had to do :

- Project->Run settings, check "Run in Terminal" (thanks Ropez)
- Qt Creator->Preferences : Environnement : General : Terminal : I had to put the whole path to XTerm. For my config, I had to put `/usr/x11/bin/xterm -e`.

Now, everything is working fine !

Comment: In my version of QTcreator (3.6.0), the tab "Project" is a vertical tab called "Projects" (with "s"). You can find it in the left of the main ide window. As for Preferences and the terminal path, it is situated in "tools > options > Environment (vertical tab) > System (Horizontal tab)"

Answer (score 14):

Go to Project -> Run settings, and make sure "Run in Terminal" is checked.

BTW:

```
std::cin >> Name;
```

is probably not what you want. It will read just a single token (typically only the first name). You should have a look at [getline](http://cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/getline/), or the [string version](http://cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I checked the 'Run in Terminal' checkbox, but now I have this problem when running my app :

Cannot start the terminal emulator 'xterm'.

Any idea ?

Comment: OK, I've never used Qt Creator on Mac, only Linux. 'xterm' is the name of the default terminal emulator on Linux. You probably need to change it to "terminal" or something like that. Again, I'm not familiar with Mac. You find this under Tools -> Options -> Environment.

Comment: FYI, I got the same error "Cannot start the terminal emulator 'xterm'". On my Fedora 15 machine I had to do a "sudo yum install xterm". Now when you run your code qtcreator can open an xterm and be successful.

Answer (score 4):

Jeromes solution is the proper one. Though I can give you a different alternative. In case you don't want to use X11 (for some reason anyhow) in the same position (QtCreator->Preferences->Environment:General:Terminal) you can give your path to the Terminal application like this:
/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app/Contents/MacOS/Terminal

Enjoy!

Comment: On Qt Creator 2.6.x this solution creates no less than 3 terminal windows and they don't pop-up above other windows so you have to click on the Dock icon to see the contents.

Answer (score 4):

Solution for Windows.

In the .pro file add:

```
QT -= core gui
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console
```

Go to Project -> Run settings, and make sure "Run in Terminal" is checked.

Answer (score 4):

I had the **"Cannot start the terminal emulator 'xterm'**" problem on Mac and fixed it by going to **settings**, **Environment** and clicking the "**Reset**" button next to the **Terminal** text field.

For some reason by default it just said "**xterm -e**" but after the reset it became an absolute path of "**/usr/X11/bin/xterm -e**".

My console app then ran fine.

Answer (score 2):

For Mac-based Qt 2.4.0, click on the Project vertical tab, which is located below the "Debug" along the same vertical line as Welcome, Edit, Design. In Target-> Run, make sure "Run in terminal" is checked!