# Qt Creator 1.3.0 and problems with console

Tags: qt-creator

I've just installed Qt Creator 1.3.0 in Ubuntu 9.10. I want to use Qt Creator 1.3.0 to develop simple console applications like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, m;

    cout << "Enter numbers: ";

    cin >> n >> m;
    cout << n << " " << m;

    return 0;
}
```

It compile. When I run it, program prints "Enter numbers: ". I enter two numbers separated with space in Application Output, but application don't react on any number.

Plz, help me. How to use standard C++ console input in Qt Creator? I've tried to use 'Run in terminal' option, but it doesn't help.

Comment: I've had this problem too. Why do you need to use Qt Creator for a console app?

Comment: Because it's the best C++ editor in Ubuntu :)

Comment: Have you tried Eclipse with CDT? Try to run the program from a real console (hit terminal and ./program) and see what happens.

Comment: Yes, i've tried CDT, but it's very huge. I prefer Qt Creator, because it's small and fast :) And of course, i tried to compile (g++) and than run my program in terminal. It works OK.

Comment: code::blocks is also worth considering

Answer (score 1):

The application output windows that you are probably referring to is exactly that, i.e. it does not allow any input. For console applications to allow input you need to check 'Run in terminal', which should open xterm.

If it does not or you want a different terminal emulator to be used, check the terminal settings in Options -> General.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the absolute path to the xterm worked for me.
See [Console input with Qt Creator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356328/console-input-with-qt-creator).

For me in Ubuntu, the Qt's default terminal only showed the output...