# Qt Creator: Run in Terminal

Tags: console, qt-creator

I want to get full console functionality running the program in Qt Creator, the same problem as described here: [Console input with Qt Creator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356328/console-input-with-qt-creator)

When I check "Run in Terminal" in configuration properties, empty terminal window is opened, without my program output. Tools - Options - General - Terminal has this value: "x-terminal-emulator -e". How can I get this working? My OS is Ubuntu 10.4.

Note: Please don't close this question, it is not duplicated! I need solution for Ubuntu OS.

Comment: ``/usr/bin/gnome-terminal -x`` worked for me in ubuntu.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Under Tools-Options-Environment-General, change the terminal value from `x-terminal-emulator -e` to 
`/usr/bin/xterm -e`. This did the trick for me.

(Found this fix here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/qtcreator/+bug/566387)

Comment: Thanks, just found the same page :)

Comment: ``/usr/bin/gnome-terminal -x`` worked for me in ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Another nice trick to avoid having to do console commands, or running a bash script is to just modify the .desktop file.

On Ubuntu those are located here:

```
ls /usr/share/applications/
```

If you wanted to edit Qt Creator for example you could do.

```
nano /usr/share/applications/qtcreator.desktop
```

Edit the variable "Exec" should look like "Exec=/usr/bin/qtcreator" and change it to.

```
bash -i -c /usr/bin/qtcreator
```

Or whatever your path to the application you want to change is.

This will enable your different environmental variables with this method as well which is what I assume you are trying to do.