# qDebug() output is not visible on a terminal

Tags: qt, terminal, ubuntu-12.04, qdebug

I use UBuntu 12.04 LTS. When I run a console application using Qt Creator an output of qDebug() is not visible on a terminal (I get only an empty terminal with a cursor). How to fix that ?

**Edit1** Moreover I can't stop a program using a stop button, I have to use a Force Quit option.

**Edit2** Here is the code:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
   qDebug()<<"Ok";
   return a.exec();
}
```

**Edit3** Solution: [Qt Creator: Run in Terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255035/qt-creator-run-in-terminal)

Comment: What Qt version you're using?

Comment: Doesn't Qt Creator print your output in output window?

Comment: Qt 4.8.1 (64 bit), Qt Creator 2.5.2. No, I get only an empty terminal

Comment: @Irbis, there is "Application Output" window in Qt Creator. Don't you see anything there?

Comment: Only this: Starting /home/xxx/MyProjects/QtProjects/consoleTest1/consoleTest1...

Comment: Do you use qInstallMsgHandler / qInstallMessageHandler?

Comment: No, I don't. See a code above.

Comment: and if you try with `#include <stdio.h>` `std::cout << "hello";` ?

Comment: stdio.h doesn't define cout; I think you want <iostream>; however, I don't think that will work either. Not sure why.