# Cant execute more than 1 line in my C++ code

Tags: c++, qt-creator

I am currently changing my programming language to C++ from matlab. So I was writing really simple code like below.When I built it I get no error message and in the screen it asks for number but it does not show it. When i try to close it it says the program is still running. I am using my laptop for this and I have just downloaded qt creator. Here I also added a screenshot .

Any idea what is going on here? Thanks a lot :)

```
 #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  int i;
  std::cout << "Please enter an integer value: " << std::endl;
  std::cin >> i ;
  std::cout << "The value you entered is" << i << std::endl;
  std::cout << " and its double is " << i*2 << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

[image: Current situation]

Comment: You need to flush the output buffer: `std::cout << std::endl;` or `std::cout.flush();`

Comment: Unable to reproduce, [works fine for me](http://ideone.com/nM5fGQ).

Comment: Dumb question but are you pressing enter after your input?

Comment: Very likely you're running in Debug in Visual Studio or something. What kind of IDE settings are you using? Did you accidentally set a breakpoint?

Comment: @AndyG I have just checked that I am not running in debug mode. My compiler is Qt Creator.

Comment: Don't put code in comments.  Please **edit** your question with the new code.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo did what you have said, changed the question accordingly (you can see) still not working !!

Comment: @Ceren That is not possible, the code you're showing compiles and runs correctly on every configuration. EDIT: are you running in console?

Comment: You might want to edit the question to explain how you're executing this program.  It's possible that those final two lines are being executed but not sticking around due to some console window closing or being cleared, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the Qt-Creator Application Output window isn't the right place to enter in from the keyboard to `cin`.  [Follow the instructions on this similar question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356328/console-input-with-qt-creator)

Comment: It's always important to explain your environment and as many details as could be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

What I see is the project in Qt Creator for Linux (actually MacOS, whatever). For me it is always executing terminal XTerm (or the other OS terminal) when I run the console program from it. Please check on project settings or try to create a console app. The culprit seems to be the input immediately in Application Output window. /*Sorry, no time to try to describe all the details on how to create a console app in Qt Creator for you*/. But: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1_aF6o6t-J4