# Qt creator run app on Mac OSX

Tags: c++, macos, qt, qt-creator

I just installed Qt creator on OSX and after compiling my first program (nothing fancy, just "hello world"), I tried to run it. It opened a terminal without my hello world, just saying "press enter to close".

I read similar topics of Stackoverflow on this matter like this one :
[Console input with Qt Creator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356328/console-input-with-qt-creator)

I did the two steps ("Run in Terminal" which was already checked by default and set the path to xterm "/usr/x11/bin/xterm -e", I checked that I had indeed xterm at this path after installing x11). But unfortunately, when I run my program, in the app output of Qt creator, I just have the message :

> Starting
>   /Users/Michael/build-First-Desktop_Qt_5_5_1_clang_64bit-Debug/First...

and then nothing else happens, no terminal. Has someone already faced this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I tried to reinstall x11 but it didn't change anything, anyone?

Comment: you should probably gives us some insight on what did you write in qt creator. also, how exactly did you tried to run your compiled app? not sure why you ask about x11