# How to input the data in c++ in the latest version of qt for non qt projects on mac?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I am using the latest version of Qt creator in mac Catalina. I have used Qt in the past earlier. I am primarily using it to run non-qt applications in C++. The version of Qt creator is 4.11.1 based on Qt 5.14.1.

I am trying to run a program written in c++ which is accepting a simple input. However, I am not sure how to input the data. I tried inputting the data into application output window of Qt but the program doesn't stop. It gets stuck forever. The program doesn't exit at all.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I tried changing the terminal in Qt setting to Mac's terminal. It does work but I would like to input the data through default Qt terminal. Let me know how to make it work. Thanks

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to enter characters in the output window. That won't work. It will not read that.

Comment: @user2672165 it doesn't accept anything at all. I tried giving numbers as well.

Comment: Have you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356328/console-input-with-qt-creator ?

Comment: @user2672165 the problem it is a very old answer, lot of things have been changed in qt now. I tried some solutions didn't work at all

Comment: This one then https://forum.qt.io/topic/74318/how-to-use-the-new-qtcreator-for-console-input-output/11 seems to be an issue with run in terminal.